# How to downgrade Rails version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, downgrade

I create my rails application in version 3.0.7.
now i want to deploy my application, but the server is only support 3.0.3

how can i downloadgrade my application?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

replace

```
gem 'rails','3.0.7'
```

with

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.3'
```

in your gemfile

Then run bundle

On a second note why not upgrade the server to rails 3.0.7?

Comment: i do not own the server. it is fix... that is why i have to downgrade...thx anyway..

Answer (score -1):

Unless I'm mistaken... you can't. Well, you can, by:

- Creating a new app
- Bundle-installing all the necessary plugins, gems, etc
- Copying over app files, configs, helpers, tests, everything
- Running tests and seeing what doesn't now work
- Making changes where required

Unfortunately, I don't believe there exists an easier way.